# PMF of a specific run in $n$ Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability

What is the PMF of a specific run of length $k$ in $n$ Bernoulli trials with $P(X_i=1)=p$? Say, what is the PMF of the string 010011 (here $k=6$) in $n$ trials ($n>k$)? This question was initiated by another question that I saw here asking about the expected value of such runs (for $p=1/2$), the answer to which is $(n+1-k)/2^k$. For $k=1$ the PMF is the binomial PMF. For $k>1$, I have thought of either using induction or to use a Markov state diagram (can be handled for $k=2$), but they can both applied to specific runs not a general run of length $k$. The closed form answer for the expected value makes me believe that there should be a shortcut to get the PMF for a general run.

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: Question edited.